# Javascript Gross & Net Pay Calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

So I am making an elementary gross pay and net pay calculator in javascript/HTML. The webpage calculator takes the user inputted hours and rate, and spits out gross pay, and gross pay with tax. For some reason, it won't display the correct formula. Somewhere I made a grave error. If someone can steer me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Heres the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Gross + Net Pay</title>
<h1>Gross + Net Pay Calculator</h1>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var rate = document.getElementById("payrate");
var hours =document.getElementById("hours");
var gross = hours * rate
var net = gross * .9 

 if (gross != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = gross;
}
 if (net != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =net;
        }

  }
</script>
<body>
<form>
Pay Rate: <input type="text" id="payrate"><br>
Hours Worked: <input type="text" id="hours"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Calculate Gross + Net Pay" onclick="myFunction()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You put your "demo" and "demo2" elements before the `<body>` tag. Why?

Comment: Because I am a noob. Should I put the body tag after h1?

Comment: The `<body>` is where the page content goes. Everything you want to see on the screen should be inside the `<body>`.

Comment: The `<script>` would usually go in the `<head>` part (which you don't have).  I'm not a super-expert so I don't know if it's OK to put it in the body, but I always put it in the head.

Comment: Typical organization:  `<html>` `<head>` ... `</head>` `<body>` ... `</body>`.  The `<title>` and `<script>` go in the head.  The page content, including the `<h1>` and `<p>`, go in the body.

Comment: Key lessons from the answer: (1) You need `.value` to retrieve the value from the `getElementById` result.  (2) If you use a `<form>`, the JavaScript will display the values, but the "submit" action will then reload the page, making the computed values disappear.  (3) JavaScript is not Java, so don't add a Java tag when asking about JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected code.  You had some typos, missing colons and you are also posting this via form.  You don't need that unless you are handling this info in a different page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Gross + Net Pay</title>
<h1>Gross + Net Pay Calculator</h1>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var rate = document.getElementById("payrate").value;
var hours =document.getElementById("hours").value;
var gross = hours * rate;
var net = gross * .9 ;

 if (gross != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = gross;
}
 if (net != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =net;
        }

  }
</script>
<body>

Pay Rate: <input type="text" id="payrate"><br>
Hours Worked: <input type="text" id="hours"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Calculate Gross + Net Pay" onclick="myFunction()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not correct at all ... still has some HTML elements outside the body tag.

Comment: @HaukurHaf Apparently Chrome is forgiving about that.  It's also forgiving about missing semicolons (actually JavaScript is OK with that).  But yes, it would be better to do it right.